# Rpi GPIO code not working

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

Following commands work well as full speed PWM.

echo "s 18 2000"    >/dev/pigpio

pigs s 18 2000

But following code do nothing. I am using Raspberry Pi4 8G B model

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# use for overwrite testing
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

print("start")
soft_pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)
soft_pwm.start(100)
time.sleep(5)
print("finish")
soft_pwm.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try soft_pwm.start(50).  I think 100 means fully on (i.e always high).

See https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/

Answer (score 0):

The code you listed will NOT do ANYTHING useful.

It will print start & stop then finish a few milliseconds later and restore GPIO state.

(I haven't verified whether the settings are correct - presumably this will set PWM 100% i.e. HIGH level.)

If you are actually trying to use a servo RPi.GPIO.PWM is not appropriate. It can be done with hardware PWM (which RPi.GPIO does not support).

Mixing 2 different libraries which operate on different principles is a bad idea; stick to ONE.

I suggest you try [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/migrating_from_rpigpio.html?highlight=pwm#pwm-pulse-width-modulation) (a frontend for RPi.GPIO) which is well documented and has extensive tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Following code did my job.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pigpio

pinNum = 23

# use for overwrite testing
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

print("start")
pi = pigpio.pi()
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pinNum, 2000)
time.sleep(5)
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pinNum, 1000)
time.sleep(5)
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pinNum, 0)
pi.stop()
print("finish")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).